# jQuery: Close Div before element to then reopen that div afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom

I'm in the middle of my container, and would like to have an image out of that container.

Right now I have something like this

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    <img />
    ...
</div>
```

And I would like to do this with jQuery

```
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>
<img />
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>
```

Here's the issue. I can't modify my code to close before and reopen after (with PHP or HTML). I'm working with WP and the `<img />` is in the middle of the content. That img src can change, and its attributes too. So I just cant regex my way out of it. Consider that everything within the container cannot be touched with PHP (if you have a way to isolate that img with PHP I'm open to it, but I dont think there is a way.)

Everything I've found with jQuery forces you that when you open a div, you close it too, and you cant just close a div before the selected element.

At the end of the day (kind of a TLDR of the whole thing), what I'm trying to do is throw a `</div>` before and a `<div class="container">` after the image. Can't seem to do it in PHP, and looking for a jQuery way to do so.

PS: I guess a vanilla js way would work too?

Comment: Is it the only image in the container?

Comment: Could be, but I would like my code to be capable to handle it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something along these lines?

https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/kcqcmp6d/ (Click "Reorder" on the top right)

```
var $container = $(".container");       //Get container
var $img = $container.find("img");      //Find image in container

$img.detach().insertAfter($container);  //Move the image to be after the container

var $newContainer = $container.clone(); //Duplicate the container
$newContainer.insertAfter($img);        //Insert the duplicated container after the image
```

---

**HTML BEFORE:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img ... />
</div>
```

**HTML AFTER:**

```
<div class="container"></div>
<img ... />
<div class="container"></div>
```